# .htaccess too many redirects for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

my main domain has SSL on it, my subdomains and addon domains do not. I have a rule currently set for my addon/sub domains in my htaccess. This has been working for all my sub/addon domains except a new one i added.

my main domain is located in public_html/ and my sub domain is located public_html/subdomain

my htaccess is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dev.maindomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

with the rewrite rule i get a too many redirect, without it, it redirects to my main domain website.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe, just took a quick look. But the first rule filters www out off the URL. And the second one, adds it to the URL. I think that is the loop. But I am not sure

Comment: Thank you koen, i tried to remove the www and it still didnt work, oddly enough, that exact code works for my three other addon domains (not sub domains so not sure if that would causes other issues.)